# Changing the margin only for the page headline

Tags: sectioning, margins, titles, chapters

I wish to change the margin only for the headlines of each page. Many of the chapters, sections and subsections in my thesis have pretty long titles and thus go out of bounds (? black box at the end) or the words stick on each other.

[image]

Is there some way I can work this around?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to show the type of document you are working with? It should start with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``.

Comment: Is it necessary to include the full titles of the chapters/sections/subsections? Usually problems like the one you are facing is not solved by stretching the margins, but by using a "short title" for the headlines while a separate "long title" is used for the table of contents and the actual sections.

Answer (score 1):

Work within the typographic constraints. There is a limited space for headlines; imagine what it would look like if a headline took up two or more lines? Eech!

The standard LaTeX classes provide commands for sectional divisions, from `part` to `subparagraph`. Taking `\section` as an example

```
\section[<text for ToC and heading>]{<title text>}
```

will use `title text` for the section's title in the document. If the optional argument is not used then this will also be used in the ToC and heading. If the optional argument is used then different texts are used in the ToC and heading.
Typically the optional argument is used to produce short texts in the ToC and heading.

The `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes) provides a second optional argument

```
\section[<text for ToC>][<text for heading>]{<title text>}
```

See the `memoir` documentation (`texdoc memoir`) for more information.

Basically, provide shorter text for the heading (and the ToC?). I can't read Greek so I'm unable to suggest what these might be.